# Why can't I rename a file from 'NAME' to 'name'?

Tags: command-line, nautilus, filesystem, files, rename

I am unable to rename a file from `RELEASE` to `release` which is currently located on  my USB flash drive. If I try to rename it through the file manager (Nautilus), it shows the error message as follows:

[image]

Also if I try to rename the same file in the terminal, I get this error message:

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:/media/avinash/89E8-9E47/DISTS/QUANTAL$ mv RELEASE release
mv: ‘RELEASE’ and ‘release’ are the same file
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:/media/avinash/89E8-9E47/DISTS/QUANTAL$
```

However, I appear to be able to rename the file to any other name like `RELEASE` to `othername`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your USB flash drive is probably formatted using a FAT filesystem. This family of filesystems is case insensitive in terms of filename uniqueness.

See also [Wikipedia: Case sensitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity) on this:

> Old Windows filesystems (VFAT, FAT32) are not case-sensitive (there cannot be a readme.txt and a Readme.txt in the same directory) but are case-preserving, i.e. remembering the case of the letters.

This means you'll have to reformat the drive to another filesystem in case you need two files with the same name except for the casing.

However, I think you can change the name of the file in two-steps:

```
mv RELEASE RELEASE-temp
mv RELEASE-temp release
```

Comment: There was 6 directories on it.On each directory there was 5 subdirectories.In each subdirectory there was minimum 10 files.In this case what can i do?

Comment: Is this applicable to NTFS too? I am able to rename my file(on an NTFS) to a same-name-different-case file.

Comment: Seems like this is only applicable to FAT fs(as you mentioned), not to NTFS(as I presumed it might be). +1 for a hackyway to rename the file.